# Combining a String and Integer to select a variable in Python

Tags: python

In python if I have a series of lists such as:

```
room1 = [1, 0, 1, 1]
room2 = [1, 0, 0, 1]
room3 = [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Then I have a integer and string such as:

```
location = 2
type = "room"
```

How can I combine the string from the variable `type` and the integer from `location` to select the relevant list and then use the value from that position in the list. For example something like this:

```
room2 = [1, 0, 0, 1]
location = 2
type = "room"
currentPos = type + location

print "%s" % currentPos[location]
```

If I combine `type` and `location` I get an error as ones a string and the others an integer. If I change location to be a string and combine both strings Python will print the `currentPos` output just as a string and I can't then use location to select the list value as this would require an integer.

```
location = "2"
type = "room"
currentPos = type + location
print "%s" %  currentPos

>>room
```

Is there a way to use a string from a variable and have python use the string output to explicitly select the name of another variable?

Comment: Do you have a good reason to not use dictionaries?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
currentPos = type + str(location)
```

Or

```
currentPos = '%s%d' % (type, location)
```

Or

```
currentPos = '{:s}{:d}'.format(type, location)
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I've rewritten my code based upon the above and its now functioning.